# glm::vec3 array to pass shader -OpenGL -GLSL

Tags: opengl, vector, glsl, shader, glm-math

I have a 3d glm vector:

```
    glm::vec3 Position[5];
```

However when I use it like this:

```
    location = glGetUniformLocation(_programHandle, "lightPos");
    glUniform3fv(location,5,  &Position[0][0]);
```

I get segmentation fault in shader vertex:

```
    uniform vec3 lightPos[5];
```

Where is the mistake in code?

Comment: There may not be a mistake in your ***listed*** code, but there is in your question... it is impossible to answer questions regarding uniform location without including the actual shaders. If the uniform is not used in your GLSL program, then it will not be assigned a location.

Answer (score 2):

Would `value_ptr(Position[0])` work any better?